# openpyxl: Fetch value from excel and store in key value pair

Tags: python, python-2.7

Have written a python script that fetches the cell values and displays in a list row by row.
Here is my script:
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file_name)
active = book.get_sheet_by_name(excel_file_name)

def iter_rows(active):
    for row in active.iter_rows():
        yield [cell.value for cell in row]

```
res = list(iter_rows(active))
for new in res:
print new
```

Output for the above script:
[state, country, code]
[abc, xyz, 0][def, lmn, 0]

I want output in below format:
[state:abc, country:xyz, code:0][state:def, country:lmn, code:0]

Please note: I want to do this from openpyxl

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do exactly what you want.

```
import openpyxl
book = openpyxl.load_workbook("Book1.xlsx")
active = book.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1")

res = list(active)
final = []

for x in range(1, len(res)):
    partFinal = {}
    partFinal[res[0][0].value] = res[x][0].value
    partFinal[res[0][1].value] = res[x][1].value
    partFinal[res[0][2].value] = res[x][2].value
    final.append(partFinal)

for x in final:
    print x
```

Comment: Thanks Nishant! I have got the desired output. please refer my another post of same question. Since the format of this question was bad to understand.